# C:Matrix times vector output

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I tried to create a matrix times vector program, but when i run the program, i found that the output is a little bit weird

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i, j, n, a[3][3], b[3], c[3];

    n = 3;

    printf("Matrix A\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = 10;
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nMatrix B\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        b[i] = 5;
        printf("%d\n", b[i]);
    }

    printf("\nA * B\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            c[i] += a[j][i] * b[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", c[i]);
    }
}
```

The result should be C = {150,150,150}. The problem seems only in c[0] and c[2]

Comment: `c` is not initialized, so you end up with random garbage in `c`, to which you add the result of the multiplication. Declare it like ` c[3] = {0, 0, 0};` or initialize it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that C does not initialise variables to 0, you must do it yourself.

Change the for loop calculating c as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    c[i]=0;      // Add this line so that c[i] can be used in: c[i] += ....
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
         c[i] += a[j][i] * b[j];
    }
}
```